# JavaScript strict mode - "this is undefined" when extending jQuery widget's property

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below are exactly the same pieces of code but one is in strict mode and another isn't.

Here it works:

```
( function ( $ ) {

    $.widget( 'ui.myWidget', $.ui.dialog, {
        // Here this is defined and successfully overwritten.
        options: $.extend( this.options, {
            someProperty: 'someValue'
        } ),
        _init: function() {
            console.log(this); // Here this is also defined.
        }
    });

} )( jQuery );
```

Here it doesn't work:

```
( function ( $ ) {

    'use strict';

    $.widget( 'ui.myWidget', $.ui.dialog, {
        // Here it says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined"
        options: $.extend( this.options, {
            someProperty: 'someValue'
        } ),
        _init: function() {
            console.log(this); // Here this is defined.
        }
    });

} )( jQuery );
```

I've read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode but still nothing comes to my mind. I just need a little hint and I'll be able to resolve this on my own.

Does anyone have any idea why it may be not working in strict mode?

I don't know if the original `$.ui.dialog` has `options` property because I'm extending a completely custom widget that has such property and the above code is just a made up example. I hope that it pictures this well. If it doesn't please request more information and I'll update the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That expression, `this.options`, is evaluated in the context of your outer function:

```
(function( $ ) {
  // ...
} )( jQuery );
```

That function is called with a plain, "naked" function call, and so in strict mode the value of `this` is `undefined`.

Looking more closely at the key portion of the code:

```
$.widget( 'ui.myWidget', $.ui.dialog, {
    // Here it says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined"
    options: $.extend( this.options, {
        someProperty: 'someValue'
    } ),
    _init: function() {
        console.log(this); // Here this is defined.
    }
});
```

The expression `this.options` looks like it's buried in the middle of a lot of stuff, but in reality it's going to have to be evaluated *before* `$.widget()` is ever called, and before `$.extend()` is called to get a value for that "options" property.

- Before calling `$.widget()`, the runtime has to evaluate all its parameters. Thus, it's got to completely build the object from that object literal.
- To build the object literal, it has to evaluate the property values. That means it has to call `$.extend()`.
- To call `$.extend()`, it has to evaluate the arguments.
- `this.options` is one of the arguments to `$.extend()`, but `this` is `undefined`. Boom.

Comment: Thank you. On http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/extending-widgets/ they say "Note how the widget factory automatically sets `this` to the widget's instance object.". Does it mean that it applies only for methods and not properties?

Comment: @Jimsea yes, that'll be true *once the widget methods are actually called*.  That hasn't happened yet in this case.

Comment: Thank you again, that explains everything. So, if I understand correctly I have to update `this.options` in `_init()` method (or anything that runs early enough) and that would be the most correct solution?

Comment: @Jimsea yes, that'd probably be the best thing. Initialize it to `null` or an empty object in that code, or else to an actual set of default options.

Comment: Just a quick update for others visiting this question: You may try `$.extend( jQuery.ui.dialog.prototype.options, { someProperty: 'someValue'  } )` and you won't have to set it in `_init`. It works but it may have a drawback with extending it multiple times (it'll inherit the options from the prototype) and you rely on the widget's name which may change.

Comment: Another quick update: You should not call it on `_init` but on `_create`. In my previous comments I wrongly assumed that `_init` runs only once when the widget is created by it turns out that the constructor is `_create` and they even mention that it already has `this.options` set: http://api.jqueryui.com/jquery.widget/#method-_create

Answer (score 1):

A key question here is how and where is your `_init()` method called (something you don't show).  `this` is set by the JS interpreter based on how a function is called.

If a function is called normally such as `x()`, then `this` will be the global object or, if in strict mode, `this` will be undefined.

If a function is called as an object method such as `foo.x()`, then the JS interpreter sets `this` to be the object reference in the method call which would be `foo` in this case.

It does not matter how a function/method is defined, only how it is called.

So, you don't show where or how your method `_init()` is called.  We would need to see that to explain exactly why you're seeing `undefined` in strict mode, but it seems likely that it's being called as a plain function, not as a method.

Remember, if you pass `obj.method` to a function as a callback function and then that is called later, that will lose its object reference and will be called as a normal function only (a common mistake).  This particular issue can be fixed either by using `.bind()` or by using a shell function to call your `obj.method()` the correct way.

For completeness sake (though not required here), `this` can be set manually by using `fn.call()` or `fn.apply()` and then passing the desired value of `this`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `_init` is described here: http://api.jqueryui.com/jquery.widget/#method-_init - it actually works in any method, not only `_init`. Now everything's clear and I see how the execution flow goes thanks to your and the other answer to this question.